# How can I get data from a specific row (eg. 6th row) in a mongoDB collection?

Tags: php, mongodb

If my data in collection mongo is something like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251ab"), "subject_slug" : "math", "lesson_slug" : "mat01" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251ac"), "subject_slug" : "math", "lesson_slug" : "mat02" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251ad"), "subject_slug" : "math", "lesson_slug" : "mat03" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251ae"), "subject_slug" : "eng", "lesson_slug" : "eng01" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251af"), "subject_slug" : "eng", "lesson_slug" : "eng02" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251b0"), "subject_slug" : "eng", "lesson_slug" : "eng03" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251b1"), "subject_slug" : "phy", "lesson_slug" : "phy01" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251b2"), "subject_slug" : "phy", "lesson_slug" : "phy02" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251b3"), "subject_slug" : "phy", "lesson_slug" : "phy03" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251b4"), "subject_slug" : "chem", "lesson_slug" : "che01" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251b5"), "subject_slug" : "chem", "lesson_slug" : "che02" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251b6"), "subject_slug" : "chem", "lesson_slug" : "che03" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4fff9946af8c6149aed251b7"), "subject_slug" : "chem", "lesson_slug" : "che04" }
```

and If I want data in row 6 without loop data. Is there short code in php to get data in that row ???

Comment: FYI, I updated the question title to refer to a "specific row" (as you've described) rather than a "random row" (which would be a slightly different answer).  If you want a random row you could do a count of the number of entries and randomly skip to find one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to find the sixth record, you need to make use of some [MongoCursor methods](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongocursor.php#mongocursor.synopsis):

- `sort()` so there is a specific order (eg. by `_id`)
- `skip()` to skip a number of records (skip 5 to find the 6th)
- `limit()` to limit to one result

Code example:

```
<?php
    $mongo = new Mongo();
    $collection = $mongo->mydb->subject;

    $query = array();
    $sort  = array('_id' => 1);

    // Find the 6th record
    $doc = $collection->find($query)->sort($sort)->skip(5)->limit(1)->getNext();

    print_r($doc);
?>
```

Sample output:

```
Array
(
    [_id] => MongoId Object
        (
            [$id] => 4fff9946af8c6149aed251b0
        )

    [subject_slug] => eng
    [lesson_slug] => eng03
)
```

Note that the performance of `skip()` may be an issue if you need to skip over a large number of documents.  A more performant option, if possible, would be to use range queries with a limit.

Comment: @crazyoxygen .. since `$collection->find()` returns a `MongoCursor`, I  used `getNext()` to get the next document from the cursor (which, in fact, is the only document that would be there with the limit of `1`).

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a json formatted content, what about reading them all into an object then json_decode them into another so that later you can just read the 6th row out.

Comment: Could you more explain please ? How can I get to direct row ?